# git-p4 submit on branch other than master?

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

I noticed that when using `git-p4 submit`, regardless of what branch I am in on git, it always sends my code to the place in p4 where I cloned it originally. That's my desired behavior when I am on the `master` branch, however, I'd like to correlate other local branches to other remote p4 branches. That is, I want to "track" or "publish" branches other than `master` from git to p4. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, although it takes a bit of setup.  Have a look at the `detect-branches` option.  You'll need to have a Perforce branch spec for each Perforce branch.

Comment: Started a thread on the Perforce forums with some more detailed steps: http://forums.perforce.com/index.php?/topic/1395-git-p4-and-multiple-branches/

Comment: After I perform the command `git-p4 clone //depot/Jam@all --detect-branches`, I get the following error: "Could not detect main branch. No checkout/master branch created." Any ideas?